# What can I use at the console to create an instance of an ActionController?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controllers

I have a Rails 2.3.11 controller that I'm trying to debug. It looks like this:

```
class AppleController < ...
  # ...

  def create
    # ...
  end
end
```

From the log, I have some parameters `p`:

```
p = { ... }
```

What can I write at the console so that I can get an instance of AppleController that will work exactly like a regular instance with those parameters, and which will let me call `.create`?

```
ac = AppleController.new
# What goes here?
ac.create
```

(Notice that just assigning `ac.params = p` is not sufficient since there's no `@request` object, etc.) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think this is best done using the [ActionController::Integration::Session](http://ap.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Integration/Session.html) class

e.g. to call the create method of your `AppleController`

```
require 'action_controller/integration'
app = ActionController::Integration::Session.new;
app.post('/apples', params) # assuming '/apples' is the path to your AppleController
puts app.response.inspect
```

Answer (score -1):

If I am reading the question correctly, you can just call `Apple.create(:something => "bah")` in the console. That should mimic what the controller does when it gets a post request.

Comment: What about things like request headers, etc.? Those wouldn't get created, would they?

Comment: If you are worried about that, then its time to move past the console, and into some functional/integration tests. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#functional-tests-for-your-controllers

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the ability to modify the code base, since I'm debugging a problem on an instance that I don't control. Believe me, writing a test is the first thing I'd do otherwise.